# Circular carousel with view on both sides of selected image

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Has anyone managed to create / modify jcarousel, bootstrap carousel or tiny carousel to achieve having a partial view on the next and previous images besides the main image on initialise?

*This is for a circular carousel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.one.org/international/

Found it! I went through each element... adjusted the widths... and set a negative margin.

I will have to calculate the screen width and image widths though before deciding what negative margin to insert... I would imagine... (screenwidth - imagewidth) / 2.

```
.jcarousel-list {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.jcarousel-container {
  margin-left: -258px; /*to be appended*/
  position:relative;
}

.jcarousel-clip {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#carousel {
  background: url("../img/lines-hatches/cr-hatch-bl.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 100% transparent;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

==== **ADDED:  ALWAYS HIGHLIGHT NEXT CONTROL OR IMAGE** ====

So that partially hidden images are not selected in controller.

```
function mycarousel_itemFirstInCallback(carousel, item, idx, state) {
    var sel = parseInt($(item).find('img').attr('data-page'));
    if(sel == $('.jcarousel-control a').length) { 
        sel = 1;
    } else {
        sel += 1;
    }
    $('.jcarousel-control a').removeClass('selected');
    $('.jcarousel-control a:nth-child(' + sel + ')').addClass('selected')
};
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel) {
    jQuery('.jcarousel-control a').bind('click', function() {
        var sel = parseInt(jQuery(this).attr('data-page'));
        sel -= 1;
        carousel.scroll(jQuery.jcarousel.intval(sel));
        return false;
    });
}
```

And in the options on init:

```
initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback,
itemFirstInCallback:  mycarousel_itemFirstInCallback
```

Comment: the tricky part would be getting a selected state on the controls, which by default, the selected would be the one in the (negative) hidden region...

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The trick is to have the viewport be smaller than your visible area, and set overflow to hidden.

In this particular instance, we used some CSS gradients to have the partial items be faded out too.

[image: Carousel]

I set the `<li>`s here to 155px each:

```
li {
  height: 115px;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  width: 155px;
```

And then the clip region to something not a multiple of 155px, in this case 700px. The trick is then to set really fat margins on both sides! This will let your extra items bleed over the edge.

```
.jcarousel-clip {
  height: 115px;
  margin: 0 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 700px;
```

Comment: My carousel is 100% of screen, with main image taking up maybe 90% of screen... so it cannot be centered like in your example. The main image (1st one) would be really spread out across the screen, unlike your 1st image. As such.. I actually need to reveal the (-1 index) image... which jcarousel expects is hidden and is changing it on move.

Comment: If u have an example page which can handle 3 large images, would be most helpful

Comment: The principle remains the same. jCarousel sets the 0th image to be at the start of `.jcarousel-clip`, so if you set a large left margin on `.jcarousel-clip`, you will see the -1 index image :)

Comment: u're right! I guess it doesn't really matter if I set the negative margin on clip level or container level either.... do you have existing code for navigation and selected navigation for this scenario?